# Change successful response to error in Angular 6+ HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular-http-interceptors

I need a HttpInterceptor which alter an Http 200 successful response into an 500 Http error.

However i have a working interceptor, but when it comes to transform a successful answer into an error, the http subscriber directly calls the "complete" handler (neither next nor error handler are beeing called).

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
      .handle(request)
      .pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>):any => {
          let type = this.convertTypeToString(event.type);
          if (type === "Response") {
            let error: HttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({status: 500});
            return Observable.create(observer => observer.error(error));
          }
          return event;
        })
      );
}
```

Expected behaviour: When i trigger e.g. a login call, i want to return - even on successful login - a Http 500 error.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is NOT to use the HttpHandler to make the call at all. Just provide an Observable which returns an error:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  let error: HttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({status: 500});
  return Observable.create(observer => observer.error(error));
}
```

HttpHandler is there to make the request "for you". But when it was an successful request, it is hard (impossible?) to redirect this to an error response. Therefore skip the next.handle()-call and simulate the call by returning an Observable.

Comment: Thank you! The most helpful part was that once you are using the next handler, there's no way to convert to an error. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use throwError Observer to return the observer form success handler.

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
      .handle(request)
      .pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>):any => {
          let type = this.convertTypeToString(event.type);
          if (type === "Response") {
            let error: HttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({status: 500});
            return throwError(err);
          }
          return event;
        })
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorSimInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return throwError(() => new HttpHeaderResponse({ status: 500}));
  }
}
```